Putting $11$ objects into rows of $5,4,3,2,2$ boxes such that no row is empty
We have 5 rows of different sizes in a sequence,
_ _ _ _ _ 5 boxes (Row 1)
_ _ _ _   4 boxes (Row 2)
_ _ _     3 boxes (Row 3)
_ _       2 boxes (Row 4)
_ _       2 boxes (Row 5)

We have to put $11$ identical objects into these boxes, with at most one object in each box, such that no row is empty.
My approach: We can calculate the number of ways in which at least one row is empty then subtract it



Empty row(s)
Number of ways




$1$
$1$


$2$
$12$


$3$
$13C11$


$4$
$14C11$


$5$
$14C11$


$3,4$
$1$


$3,5$
$1$


$4,5$
$12$



So total cases is
$$A:=1+12+(13C11)+2(14C11)-1-1-12$$
(as the last three cases occur twice in above)
Final answer- $$16C11 - A,$$
But the answer is not matching, I cannot figure out which case I missed, kindly help... (nCr represents no. Of ways of selecting r objects out of n)

For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, e.g., here, here, here and here.

This is hard to read.  I suggest looking at the $5$ empty boxes.  Count the good ways to choose these.

My approach is similar only, I just removed the cases when atleast one row is empty

i saw when 1 row is empty, then when 2 row is empty, like when 1 row is empty( suppose R3) , one case includes R3 and R4 empty), and when R4 is empty it includes R3 empty,so (R3 and R4 ) empty is counted twice , so remove it once

Why is there 1 way row 1 camn be empty and  12 ways for row 2, to be empty, for example ?

I don't see a problem, but it's a fairly error prone sort of count.  What is the official answer?

@trueblueanil  There are exactly  $5$ empty boxes.  The only  way for $R_1$ to be empty is if all $5$ of those boxes are empty and all $11$ of the other boxes are filled.  Now, $R_2$ only has $4$ boxes.  So if all those are empty the other empty box could be in any of the $16-4=12$ positions, so there are $12$ arrangements with $R_2$ empty.  And so on.

What is the given answer you're comparing against?  If that answer is numerical, what was your answer?  Often this information can let us reverse engineer the issue (why did you omit it, anyway?)

Your option n°3 is : Row n°3 is empty ; you should rephrase it : Row n°3 is empty, and only this row is empty.  To avoid duplicates with last options. And if you rephrase it, you also need to recompute it.

And finally, what you will do is applying a well known result : 'law of inclusion/exclusion'. You don't really need to know this result, you will discover it by yourself.

You need also to rephrase options n°4 and n°5.

What do u means by rephrase @Lourrran

Your option n°3 is now :  R3 empty. you count 13C11 ways. Correct. Your option n°6 is "R3 and R4 both empty" ; you count 1 way. Correct. The problem is that at the end, you add these 2 numbers (plus some others ...) ; So you have duplicates. Either you change your option n°3, option n°4 and option n°5, (= you rephrase those options) to reduce the  scope, and avoid duplicates when you will sum all options ; either you look at 'inclusion/exclusion principe' ; it will explain you the same thing , with other words.

It is correct! The answer is $3563$. I checked with this brute force Sage-code:
rowLens = [5,4,3,2,2]
ans = 0
for a in Compositions(11, outer=rowLens, length=5):
    ans += prod(binomial(b,x) for b,x in zip(rowLens,a))
print (ans) #3563

And the I-E is
binomial(16,11)-1-12-binomial(13,11)-2*binomial(14,11)+1+1+12 #3563


Even with little exposure to the method outlined below, you could use it with advantage
Note that selecting 11 is same as taking out 5, which is easier.
So if we choose $4$ to remove from row $1$, we can write it as $\binom54x^4$, the exponent of $x$ indicating that $4$ items have been removed.
The expression $(x^0+\binom51x^1+\binom52x^2+\binom53x^3+\binom54x^4)$ would thus stand for all the permissible ways we can remove objects from row $1$
Writing expressions for other rows similarly, and multiplying them all together, since exponents get added when polynomials are multiplied, all we need is to find the coefficient of x^5 in
$\small{(1+5x+10x^2+10x^3+5x^4)(1+4x+6x^2+4x^3)(1+3x+3x^2)(1+2x)^2}$
and the answer we get is $\boxed{3563}$
